# jquery autocomplete IE 9 not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to autocomplete in a input,  It is working fine in Chrome,Safari&Firefox . It is not working on IE 9 alone. Please help.

```
    $("#name").autocomplete({
    select: function(event, iu) {
            id = event.toElement.innerText.split('-')       
            $("#id_estudiante").val(id[1]);
            $("#FinancieroGrid").load('php/Financiero/librerias/FindStudent.php?action='+id[1].replace(' ',''));                
          },
    source:'php/Financiero/function/getstuden.php',
    minLength:1
});
```

Comment: Not sure if this makes any difference, but shouldn't there be a `;` after `id = event.toElement.innerText.split('-')`?

Comment: @Niffler `;` in JS isn't necessary as new line does the job too.

Comment: @Al3more which bit isn't working? Do you get `id`?

Comment: i just testing, but the problem persist... Is important say than when i write in a input, the Jquery  brings the data, but not let me select in IE. PD: Sorry for my english

Comment: After `id = event.toElement.innerText.split('-') ` add  `alert(id)`, do you see that `id` is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 does not like `.innerText`, versions 9+ use `.textContent` so rather than muck about, replace this

```
id = event.toElement.innerText.split('-')
```

with jQuery's own method

```
id = $(event.target).text().split('-');
```